# Como hago un UPDATE a el ultimo registro?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy haciendo varias consultas de Insertar a una base de datos, y lo que quiero es que mientas hago un insert mas abajo haga un update siempre al ultimo registro.

```
string ins = "UPDATE Articulo 
              SET Cod_Costo="+CC+",Cod_ITBIS="+CI+",Cod_Precio="+CP+ " 
              WHERE Cod_Articulo=MAX(Cod_Articulo)";
```

Trate con la consulta de arriba pero el SQL Server no lo permite, obtengo este mensaje de error:

> No puede aparecer un agregado en la cláusula WHERE si no es en una subconsulta contenida en una cláusula HAVING o en una lista de selección, y siempre que la columna agregada sea una referencia externa

Comment: ¿Dicha consulta que resultado te arroja?

Comment: No puede aparecer un agregado en la cláusula WHERE si no es en una subconsulta contenida en una cláusula HAVING o en una lista de selección, y siempre que la columna agregada sea una referencia externa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basándonos en el mensaje de error que obtuviste al tratar de ejecutar dicha consulta puedes:

- Mover la selección del valor máximo a una subconsulta
- Construye un `SELECT` completo que tome el valor máximo dle código

Quedando tu consulta así:

```
UPDATE Articulo 
              SET Cod_Costo="+CC+",Cod_ITBIS="+CI+",Cod_Precio="+CP+ " 
              WHERE Cod_Articulo= (SELECT MAX(Cod_Articulo) FROM tuTabla)
```

En la documentación de SQL Server<sup>1</sup> puedes observar que:

- En el `SET` estableces que te devuelva solo un valor escalar

**Referencias**

- <sup>1</sup> [Update con funciones de agregación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#i-specifying-a-subquery-in-the-set-clause)